# Which SE website should I ask my question about a web design framework on?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

I would like a site recommendation. I want to ask a question about how to use Bootstrap 5 (a Web design framework) to implement a type of web page design. In other words, about how to use Bootstrap 5 in a common but undocumented way.

I thought that [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com) would be the right place, but I can't find any relevant tags, and at least one is required. I guess that Bootstrap 5 is not considered an App.

I posted on Super User, but it closed the question as off-topic.

I've searched through the tags AND the list of SE websites and cannot find the proper place to post my question. Perhaps it doesn't fit anywhere in what SE has been used for so far? If this is the case, should I create a new SE site about Web Design, or perhaps Web Frameworks?

Answer (score 4):

The problem might not be the topic itself; Stack Overflow has [plenty of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-5) about Bootstrap 5. But the Stack Exchange network is most suitable for questions like 'I'm using [framework X] to achieve [objective Y] but I'm running into [problem Z]'. Just asking 'I'm using [framework X], how can I achieve [objective Y]' is [too broad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and searching for the right site or proposing a new Stack Exchange site in [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) won't help.

(In particular, WebApps.SE is about *using* web applications, not *developing/designing* them; check [their Help Center](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).)

Comment: Well, I would appreciate a site recommendation. I'm not allowed to post on SO, so I hope another site will work. And I'll look around for other Bootstrap 5 sites, thanks. It's interesting that my meta question has received 4 votes already. Perhaps we need a new SE site for web design, or web frameworks, or both?